# Cannot install Code::Blocks IDE on Debian 8 Jesse

Tags: linux, debian, codeblocks

I am trying to install `codeblocks 16.01` on 64 bit Debian Jessie. For some reason I cannot. I downloaded the file  `codeblocks_16.01_amd64_jessie.tar.xz`  from the `codeblocks` [download page](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26#linux64) .

Inside this file there are many .deb files - [image: The .deb files in the download]

I have tried to install both amd64.deb and common_16.01_all.deb graphically by right-click -> open with -> package install

when I try this it does not work. A window pops up saying "Failed to instal files: An unspecified transaction error has occured. More information is available in the detailed report."

If I knew where to find this detailed report I would paste it here. That would be very helpful.

Something different happens when I try to install codeblocks-common_16.01_all.deb graphically. My password is prompted then an "Installing Packages" loading bar window appears. Then that window disappears. When I go into my program finder to launch codeblocks there is no icon to launch the program. I assume that means that the program is not installed.

Any other .deb files just do the same thing as amd64.deb - "An unspecified transaction error has occured."

I would really like some help installing this ide. Maybe I have to install another package in this folder? The download page for codeblocks does not detail exactly what I have to do.

I will try my best to provide any information you need if you ask for it. Thanks you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install `codeblocks` from backports as mentioned [@Steh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40573571/5848185):

```
apt edit-sources
```

add the following line:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
```

Save and update:

```
apt update
```

check it with `apt-cache policy codeblock`:

```
codeblocks:
Installed: (none)
Candidate: 16.01+dfsg-2~bpo8+1
Version table:
  16.01+dfsg-2~bpo8+1 0
     100 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages
```

install it:

```
apt-get -t jessie-backports install codeblocks
```

**from the tarball**:

install the required package:

Install the compiler.

```
apt-get install build-essential
```

Install the debugger:

```
apt-get install gdb
```

Install `wxWidgets` library

```
apt-get install libwxgtk2.8-0
```

Install the `wxWidgets` developement packages:

```
apt-get install libwxgtk2.8-dev
```

Download the tarball from [here](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26) then extract it:

```
wget http://netix.dl.sourceforge.net/project/codeblocks/Binaries/16.01/Linux/Debian%20Jessie/codeblocks_16.01_amd64_jessie.tar.xz
tar xvf codeblocks_16.01_amd64_jessie.tar.xz
```

Change directory and Install all the packages :

```
dpkg -i *.deb
```

Comment: This got codeblocks installed in under a minute while I spent hours fiddling around with .deb files. Thanks so much! I used the command line method.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the package `codeblocks` via package manager using Jessie's backports.

Instructions on how to install backports can be found [here](https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/).

In general, it is good practice to prefer the package manager over manual installation whenever possible. You can use the Debian package search to look for specific programs.